# Merge two identical CSV from the same directory - Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with the same structure in a CSV. I want to read both CSV and merge them to create one bigger data frame. In the directory there are only the two data frames.

The first CSV is called "first":

```
ad   7   8
as   5   8
ty   9   y
```

The second CSV is called "second":

```
ewtw   5   2
as     1   2
ty     4   9
```

My code is:

```
  import os
  import pandas as pd

  targetdir = "C:/Documents and Settings/USER01/Mis documentos/experpy"



  filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 

  for file in filelist :
      df_csv=pd.read_csv(file) 
      big_df = pd.concat(df_csv)
```

Unfortunately, it didn’t work. How Can I fix that?

Comment: make a list of df_csvs in the for loop call it l. then do pd.concat(l) outside of the loop. pd.concat takes a list as a param not a single dataframe.  you can use drop_duplicates after if you need it

Answer (score 0):

concat takes a list or dict of series: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html, so what you can do is make a list of the dataframes and concat them all together to make your big df:

```
filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 

df_list=[]
big_df=None
for file in filelist :
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))

big_df = pd.concat(df_list,ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively you can append:

```
filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 

big_df=None
for file in filelist :
    big_df.append(pd.read_csv(file), ignore_index=True)
```

I think you should change your path to this:

```
targetdir = r'C:\Documents and Settings\USER01\Mis documentos\experpy'
```

The above uses a raw string avoids the ambiguous parsing of slashes on Windows systems

Comment: I’ve tried your first code but there’s a message which says: “File first.csv does not exist”

Comment: Can you print your file's and check if they are valid, I cannot help you with your error as it's local to your PC

Comment: I don’t know if it helps but "targetdir" is not inside the working directory of Ipython Notebook which I use.

Comment: Try setting targetDir to this `targetdir = r'C:\Documents and Settings\USER01\Mis documentos\experpy'`

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to have only two CSVs then you may just want to use `pd.merge`

```
first = pd.read_csv( 'first.csv' ) # insert your file path
second = pd.read_csv( 'second.csv' ) 
big_df = (first, second, how='outer') # union of first and second
```

Comment: The problem is that the example of my question is just a simplifcation. I really want to merge 30 csv in one csv.

Comment: (unfortunately i'm new to SO so I can only comment here :\) I think EdChum's solution should work, try using `targetdir+file` as the path instead of just `file`

you may need to add an extra slash for your targetdir